# How can open href at python?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to open `'text'` botton but I can't open it.
How can I do?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://www.pdfescape.com/account/unregistered/")
time.sleep(0.5)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("dStartNew").click()
time.sleep(0.5)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("PdfNew_input_pc").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[value=\"2\"]").click()
#time.sleep(0.5)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("PdfNew_input_ps").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[value=\"a4\"]").click()
#time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PdfNew_form"]/input[1]').click()
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('Add-Text').click()
```

Problem code : `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('Add-Text').click()`

Comment: The last element you tried to click has no class name - it's title is "Add Text".

Comment: i see no Add Text button. Nor is there a title element of that name as far as I can see. There is a title attribute of [title="Select PDF Text Tool"] which has an id #dHeaderSelect  but this is not visible on the page (using Chrome) in such a way I would expect a user to be interacting with it.

Answer (score 1):

The element you wanted to click has no class name - it has the title "Add Text", also you are using find_elements instead of find_element which changes the result type.

So you could select it with:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[title=\"Add Text\"]').click()
```

Also please let me add another improvement:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PdfNew_form"]/input[1]').click()
```

could be much more stable (for the case of page changes) written as:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type=\"submit\"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('Add-Text'),click()
```

1. Above code should return a list of elements and you can not click on list of elements
2. This element is not present in the DOM
3. To click we use '.' instead of ','